# ffmpeg encode tiff to h265- error At least one output file must be specified

Tags: cmd, ffmpeg

I need to convert tiff images into h265 file.
I'm using the following command:

ffmpeg -y -framerate 30 -i input.tiff -c:v libx265 -x265-params no-open-gop=1:min-keyint=4:keyint=4:bitrate=60 -preset medium -f ssegment -segment_time %ST% "outputfile.265" 2>&1

I get an output of "error At least one output file must be specified".
What am i missing? 
Is there anything i need to do to activate my use of 265? 
Im using ffmpeg vs.3.4.1

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Share full log.

Answer (score 0):

As Mulvya said, please share full log. Because this worked for me:
`ffmpeg -y -framerate 30 -i ./lzw.tiff -c:v libx265 -x265-params no-open-gop=1:min-keyint=4:keyint=4:bitrate=60 -preset medium -f ssegment -segment_time 0:0 "outputfile-%03d.265" 2>&1`

The `tiff` file downloaded from here: http://users.wfu.edu/matthews/misc/graphics/formats/formats.html